# Files not attached when forwarding emails (Classic)

Tags: email, attachment, files, salesforce-classic

In classic when you forward an email containing attachments, they are automatically included on the email; you see them below the email editor in the `Attachments` section.

This is not the case for `Files`.  Is there any way to get files to automatically forward like `Attachments` do in classic, or is this behaviour exclusive to lightning?

Comment: Are you trying to forward email attachments sent from Salesforce Classic in Lightning Experience?

Comment: No we're still in Classic (in the process of getting ready to move over) and we've moved from Attachments to Files.  In Classic, clicking the Forward button would also forward attachments; but now we've moved to Files, these aren't included in the forward.  Our users are having to download the files and manually attach them to the email.